# How to make functions as protected into library module's classes?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-library, jitpack

I am trying to generate a library module for my android project and I am able to do that, and deployed this one to Jitpack. But when I  use this library module(as jitpack dependency ) than using "jump to function" method I am able to check the complete code of the particular function which should not. I tried to make these functions as private but in that case I am not able to use these functions into my project.

Please suggest me appropriate solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't.  You can always decompile Java code.  At best, you can use obfuscation to scramble the variable names.  But the code and logic will always be available.

Comment: @GabeSechan  but there are so many libraries when we call their functions than when we check these functions by jump to functions than it shows only the functions not it's body and logics

Comment: Only the Android framework, which is a special case because the code isn't being directly included in your app but is linked to from the device.  Anything in your app requires the entire bytecode to be downloaded, which means it can be trivially decompiled.